# VB Declaration and C++ DLL call

Tags: vb.net, pinvoke

I'm calling a function in a library ("wow64ext.dll") with this declaration

Declaration in C++ library:

```
extern "C" __declspec(dllexport) DWORD64 __cdecl GetModuleHandle64(wchar_t* lpModuleName)
```

My declaration in the VB.net program is:

```
Public Declare Function GetModuleHandle64 Lib "wow64ext.dll" (ByRef lpModuleName As String) As ULong
```

Now when I call this function via

```
Dim ntqipHandle as Ulong = GetModuleHandle64("ntdll.dll")
```

it throws a exception: "*Managed Debugging Assistant 'PInvokeStackImbalance' has detected a problem in 'MyCode.vshost.exe'.*"

What am I doing wrong here?

*(I'm fully aware that this might be a **silly** question. Nevertheless so many people over at [xsimulator.net](http://www.xsimulator.net/community/) will be happy when you help me to resolve it :) )*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a few problems. One is the calling convention. The unmanaged code uses cdecl. Your code uses stdcall. The other problem is the strings. The unmanaged code uses UTF-16 text, your code uses ANSI encoded text. And passing `ByRef` is wrong too. Using `Declare` is not advisable these days. That was how you did things in the old VB6 days. Now that we have VB.net you should use p/invoke. It is much more flexible and capable.

Fix it all up like this:

```
<DllImport("wow64ext.dll", CallingConvention := CallingConvention.Cdecl, _
    CharSet := CharSet.Unicode)> _
Public Function GetModuleHandle64(ByVal lpModuleName As String) As ULong
End Function
```

Comment: Hi DavidThank you so much for your quick answer.
Your code works right away and I can continue reading 64-bit memory from a 32-bit program and coding plugins for xsimulator.net :)

Answer (score 2):

You are missing `__cdecl` and you should pass strings `byval`.

```
<DllImport("wow64ext.dll", CallingConvention:=CallingConvention.Cdecl, CharSet:=CharSet.Unicode, ExactSpelling:=True)> _
Public Function GetModuleHandle64(ByVal lpModuleName As String) As ULong
End Function
```

Comment: Thank you both for your quick answers! Works like a charm now :)
(and I have learned a lot ;)